# Database relationship diagram - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

There are multiple DB relationship diagram found during product support.I searched on internet to get meaning of these diagram; however, none of the database diagrams(that are on internet) are seems similar to mine (pl see attached images) and also, I'm seeing this type if diagrams for 1st time. Could any one has come across such DB designed diagram**(Marked in RED)**. Please clarify and help me to understand.Thanks.

[image: What this red boxed relationship mean?]

[image: What this red boxed relationship mean?]

Comment: try to use - https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/studio/database-diagram.html#header

Comment: The first one looks like http://wiki.marandcustomsolutions.com/exec/version?name=Entity+Relationship+Diagram&version=9

Comment: Looks quite obvious that it means 1 Client - many Trusts. The side with many bars means...many.

Comment: What that small circle means? Also, what about that arrow(s) ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand well your question, but if your question is about understand this diagrams, you can read the information that is in this link and i think that you can understand the diagrams and the arrows (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/java.817/a81358/05_dev1.htm). I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for this link. However, my diagram (RED marked) is different. I need to exactly understand what that mean?

Comment: I know this, but if you understand this i think that it's easy for you understand yours diagrams.. I find this too (http://www.smartdraw.com/entity-relationship-diagram/) that you can see.. for example in you first diagram means that you can have 0 or 1 Client to 0 or 1 and only 1 Trusts.. but you can read this in this 2 links that i send you. I hope this helps you.